# Stacking Authorization in MVC3 Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to stack several custom `AuthorizeAttribute` on a controller?

I tried doing something like this:

```
[IsOwner]
[IsFranchisee]
public class CartController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

but it's behavior is erratic. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't (mostly the latter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your implementation is correct?
I'm asking because there is no guaranteed order with `FilterAttributes`, (which `AuthorizeAttribute` derives from) unless you set the `Order` property.

Because you said the behavior is erratic, I was thinking maybe one attribute cancels the other out. For example your user `IsOwner == true`, but `IsFranchisee == false`. Maybe whether or not permission is granted depends on which executes first?

So, you could try giving your attributes an order property and see if the behavior is still erratic

Comment: Didn't think of that. But I changed my implementation in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. If you like at the source for the `AuthorizeAttribute`, it has `AllowMultiple = true`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for dynamic authorization, the controller or action is given a single [Authorize] annotation and then inside the controller or action the authorization is handled.